# TableRow in android

Tags: android, tablerow

I have a problem. I should add that I get the data from a database and put them into a table in a consecutive manner. This is the part of the code where I get the data:

```
       String s = "";
   JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

   for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
       JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
       lu=json.getString("Locale");
       s = s + 
               "Locale : "+json.getString("Locale")+"\n"+
               "Lunedì : "+json.getString("Lunedi")+"\n"+
               "Martedì : "+json.getString("Martedi")+"\n"+
               "Mercoledì : "+json.getString("Mercoledi")+"\n"+
               "Giovedì : "+json.getString("Giovedi")+"\n"+
               "Venerdì : "+json.getString("Venerdi")+"\n"+
               "Sabato : "+json.getString("Sabato")+"\n"+
               "Domenica : "+json.getString("Domenica")+"\n"+
               "Info : "+json.getString("info")+"\n\n";
   }
```

how can I do? Thanks.